# Forcing a new tag by writing an offtopic question

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I just stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26561576/508666):

[What is DAO programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26561576/508666)

Which I feel is where OP just created a question to force the creation of a tag. Imho the question is offtopic on the grounds of being too broad (I close-voted as such). The answer imho would be a perfect fit once the tag is actually created using a real question.

Was I wrong (about the offtopicness and the value for a possible tag wiki in the future)?

**EDIT**

While I was typing this I apparently became an idiot:

> REMOVED, DUE TO AN IDIOT'S OPINION.

and OP removed the question. The question still stands: was I in the wrong here?

Screeny for non 10k users:

[image]

Comment: I think you're in the right - I VtC'd this too. Noble intention, wrong execution IMO

Comment: I'd expect this to happen with a fairly low-rep user. **But a 20k+ user?**

Comment: This question should have been closed - not due to it being too broad - but because it is off-topic because it's literally off-topic. It's asking for external resources. M M should know better.

Comment: I've seen worse questions upvoted hundreds of times - I actually think its a good question/answer pair. [Here's one that is basically identical, with over 1000 votes between question & answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028250/what-is-functional-reactive-programming?lq=1)

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Not sure if you mean the OT question or rudeness, but both are a huge failure from a 20k-er. Actually, even from a 10k-er, because [they are expected to lead by example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools): *As one of our most experienced users, we're counting on you to guide the community and lead by example.* Maybe that is why the [Be Nice™](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) policy has been refactored lately.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> Was I wrong?

No.

That's way too broad a question, no doubt about it. Stack Overflow's not meant to replace a whole language's docs, certainly not in one single question.

The answer could indeed be part of the tag's wiki once the tag is established though.

> I apparently became an idiot.

Welcome to the club!

Comment: "Welcome to the club!" do we have a special handshake or something like that? Or how do I recognize you all?

Comment: Yeah well we do have a secret handshake. But we're such idiots no one ever remembers what it is...

Comment: @Mat: isn't it the [One-Finger Salute](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-C5mtZlCo_mo/U0vJ-hgB9XI/AAAAAAAAHCE/pQvqwMG1jW8/s1600/funny-greeting-card-middle-finger.jpg) then?

Answer (score 13):

The proper thing for the OP to have done would have been to tackle [standard programming problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trabb_Pardo%E2%80%93Knuth_algorithm) in Dao (tagged with dao-lang) and then used the opportunity to create the tag wiki into which he could put the proper (not plagiarized) information.

The question, as asked and answered was not a good fit for the style of Q&A that is within the scope of Stack Overflow.  It could be closed as unclear (what is the problem) or too broad (consider the possible answers to "What is C++?" or "What is Java?" - there are books and pages upon pages of specifications and wikipedia articles describing that).

Comment: "What is a programming language? A miserable little pile of secrets..."

Comment: Not quite the "What is Java?" example you joked about, but here is ["What is Java EE?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/106820/what-is-java-ee)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier that one, and the 'what is functional programming' are both from very early days of Stack Overflow.  Things were different then.  The problem is you get answers like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1040163/289086) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/108924/289086) for which people don't appear to be doing a good job of cleaning those up. That type of question, while popular and possibly informative, doesn't encourage good answers and discourage bad ones, thus the question itself is arguably a poor one.

Comment: "Things were different then." Indeed, that is my point. I disagree with the changes. I believe we have set various precedents on this site, and should be more consistent. If those earlier questions are now off topic, they should also be deleted. However, I believe those, and this new one, are all perfect candidates for the site.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier however, there are other, better mechanisms today for providing the information that wasn't available (or fully realized - not that I'm saying that tag wikis are yet fully realized for their potential even today).  The thing is, there *is* a better way of handling this. The [tag:functional-programming] and [tag:java-ee] tags have the potential to be much more than they currently are and would serve as a better, long term storage of such material.